# Programmatically lock and unlock iPhone (not jailbroken) screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Can we programmatically lock and unlock Screen of the iPhone?

Heard of GSEventLockDevice() (private API) from GraphicsServices.framework but is not working in higher iOS versions.

Please checkout the following video:
https://vimeo.com/188356953

**Don't know how the iPhone screen is getting locked programatically in Cellcontrol !**
  Any ideas are welcomed !

Comment: Are you developing for jailbroken devices? These won't work on non-jailbroken devices.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832940/programmatically-lock-and-unlock-iphone-screen

Comment: @kennytm  No, but the Cellcontrol app is doing it . In App Store !

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Not working for higher iOS versions.

Comment: @swathykrishnan - there is no public api available for this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Ya i know. But there's some workaround. And Cellcontrol have done it

Comment: @swathykrishnan - may be those are used the app with special permisson granted by apple

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Might be. So for that what i need to do ! Any suggestions ?

Comment: Also, no offense, but are you sure they lock the device? Its hard to check this, since there is no way to register an account without paying. Maybe they simply present a screen that is terribly similar to iPhone lock screen and block the actual device lock (since this can be done easily)?

Comment: @swathykrishnan - on your submission request to apple , may be if apple granted it comes to live else your app will be rejected

Comment: On the linked video, there is no "lock"/"unlock", it's just posting notification (user has to type its password to unlock the phone) and need to be connected to a device (guess bluetooth? that manage stuff).

Comment: @Larme Thanks for that. I'm already using a hardware part via bluetooth. I think this will do rest of my job.

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489038/force-lock-screen/36478975

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't lock the screen programmatically without any private API but your requirement can achieve by sending keyboard events from paired bluetooth hardware devices.

Please check this link [Force lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489038/force-lock-screen/36478975)

Answer (score -3):

There is no documentation given by Apple to do it. 
But there are some private API's which can be possible to do it but it is not accepted by Apple when you submit your app to AppStore.

So be specific on it whether you are going to submit in AppStore or Private purpose.

But you can keep your device **unlock** from auto lock by using the below line.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```